# Python code to iterate through folder and 'get' file name and put into list

Tags: python

I have a folder with 10  files excel files inside, the files end with the name 'AA.xlsx', 'BB.xlsx' etc I need a code to get the last last two letters and put this into a list, and I need it for all 10 files.

So something like this; [AA, BB, CC, CD, HN...]

Also, the files paths are like this ;

'2019-10-02_xxx_2018-12-31_GB00Bvvvv_Hooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyn_30163-000-HN.xlsx'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import os

path = "C:/path/to/folder"

for root, dir, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    codes = [name[-7:-5] for name in files]
    # [-7:-5] will only work of all files have '.xlsx' as extension.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
files = [file[-7:-6] for file in os.listdir("<path>")]
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

Comment: This works, but not all the files are the same length. so not all last two characters are in the list

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `re` for this, and just match all the `.xlsx` files

```
import os
import re

FOLDER_DIR = '<path to the folder that contains your files>'
ENDING_PATTERN = r'([A-Z]{2}).xlsx$'

file_endings = []

for _, _, files in os.walk(FOLDER_DIR):
    for fileName in files:
        matches = re.findall(ENDING_PATTERN, fileName)
        if matches:
            file_endings.append(matches[0])

print(file_endings)
```

This uses a regex pattern `([A-Z]{2}).xlsx$` which matches all `.xlsx` files that end with 2 uppercase letters.